# what is the meaning of the word "this" in Jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm a newcomer in JavaScript and JQuery language. I started to see some examples of JQuery script.

i have the following code segment:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

   $("p").click(function(){

   $(this).hide();

    });

  });

</script>
```

My question: what is the meaning of word **"this"** in this line of code:

```
          $(this).hide();
```

Comment: Look in to the related section.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm not sure what you're referring to, although that's not very nice.

Comment: The accepted answer here may give you some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552110/using-the-context-of-the-this-keyword-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to each of `p` tags *in your selector `$("p")`* that gets clicked. For example, you can see html of each `p` tag you clicked on like this:

```
$("p").click(function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Notice also that `$(this)` and `this` in above context mean different things. The latter `this` refers to DOM element itself which won't have jQuery methods/properties available to it, for example:

```
$("p").click(function(){
   alert(this.html());
});
```

Won't work because `html()` won't be available because `this` refers to DOM element in there. So if you want to use jQuery methods, use `$(this)` instead.

Comment: I think it's important to add (see in the answer linked in the comments by @rsbarro) that if you use naked `this` you have a plain html element, but you get a jQuery object when you wrap it with `$(this)`.  You can call the usual jQuery methods when it is wrapped.

Comment: **This is bad that you down-voted other answers to keep your one at top.**

Comment: @Shiplu: I didn't down vote any answers here. I myself got a down vote. BTW, don't blame anyone that way. Should I down vote you now to prove that I didn't ? Since you said so, I believe you are the one who down voted me :)

Comment: Sorry @Sarfraz.two -1 should make -2. That why I though you did it.  It was quite confusing

Comment: @Sarfraz: lol.  There are evident flaws in the voting system, but I initially thought the same as Shiplu - I had left him a comment thinking it was one of your supporters, but then I removed it

Answer (score 2):

Most time in such snippets of jQuery `this` refers to `HTMLElement` object. Here `this` is the `HTMLParagraphElement` or `P` tag object.
`$(this)` refers to the `jQuery` object created from current `HTMLElement` object.

But keep in mind in JavaScript the meaning `this` changes depending on where the function is called.

Comment: i guess the -1 is because, this is refers to the element in use. not the getElementById() (getElementById === $('#element') || $('element').attr('id')).

Comment: @MichelAyres I got minus before I add that statement. I added that to clarify that object name. Its alwasy `HTMLElement`, `HTMLParagraphElement` just inherits the parent `HTMLElement`. getElementById!=$("#element") I know this. `$(this)` and `this` are different. I also had explained it there.

Answer (score 2):

- `$('p')` will add one or more paragraph elements (wrapped in jQuery magic) to an array
- `.click()` is a jQuery function that will be called on each of the paragraph elements found (in the array)
- `function(){...}` is the definition of that click event, where you can perform any javascript option when the paragraph is clicked
- `this` is a global variable that refers to the calling DOM object, which I believe is `window` by default, but in this instance it would be each paragraph HTML element.

Because you want to call a jQuery function (`hide()`) on the paragraph element, you have to wrap the base (HTML/DOM) object with all the jQuery functions, which is what `$(this)` does; it takes `this` and adds all the jQuery stuff to it, to turn it into a jQuery object, so that you can call all the jQuery functions.  In other words:

- `this` is the base object
- `$(this)` is almost the same, but its a jQuery object, which inherits the object in scope, so that you can call all the jQuery sugar you want

Comment: Sarfraz is down-voted without explaining. He down-voted both the other answers. He got -2 for this as I see his profile.

Comment: It is very very bad to blame anyone without proof at minimum. In case you guys think I did it. Will you both guys allow me to down vote both of you to prove that I did not down vote? Also mr shiplu down voted me with his comment which is very bad....

Comment: Sorry, my bad for downvoting.  I now realize I did not read your answer correctly.  I read that `this` is `window` and downvoted without reading further. My vote is locked.

Comment: That's understandable, I was more curious than anything.  I don't mind being wrong, I just like to correct my answers when I am