# Applying staggered and randomised left / right placement for each wordpress post with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, each

So I'm trying to make each individual post (.card) on a WordPress site stagger, some more to the left, some to the right, and for this to be a random amount and to change on refreshing the page.

This is where I am at with the JavaScript code to try and do this:

```
//random position 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.card').each(function () {
        $('.card').css({
            'left': (Math.random() * 900) + 50
        })
    });
});
```

I don't think I am using the 'each' method correctly? It randomly places them left / right, but it applies the same distance to all posts, instead of each one being at a different distance.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: use `$(this).css`. `this` will represent each of the items when you loop through them in `.each`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and learn more about `this` keyword from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481439/jquery-this-keyword)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.card').each(function() {
    $(this).css({'left' : (Math.random() * 900) + 50})
  });
});
```