# Why compare element to this keyword?

Tags: javascript, this, event-delegation

I am looking at the following [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q6Aafx11IW6CnC8k?p=preview&preview) which is a part of event delegation [documentation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

In the link, we have the followig

```
let table = document.getElementById('bagua-table');

    let selectedTd;

    table.onclick = function(event) {
      let target = event.target;

      while (target != this) {
        if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
          highlight(target);
          return;
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
      }
    }
```

I am just unable to understand why the following `while (target != this)`. I understand that the `this` keyword here refers to the entire table since that is the object in play but why write a loop in this manner?

Maybe my understanding of this is not as deep. If someone could please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery $(this) keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481439/jquery-this-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

What this does is, the `target` starts at the event's target - the innermost element the event was dispatched to. Then it searches the target, then its ancestor, then its ancestor, and so on. The first one that matches the condition `target.tagname == 'TD'`, if any, will result in `highlight` being called and the loop ending. If no elements match, then the loop will continue until the target is `this` - the table - and will end at that point.

But this is pretty confusing code. Using `.closest` would be much easier, since it will find the first ancestor matching a selector.

```
table.onclick = (event) => {
  const td = event.target.closest('td');
  if (td) highlight(td);
};
```

If nested tables are a possibility, and you don't want the event to go outward past the table in question, include the table in the selector string:

```
table.onclick = (event) => {
  const td = event.target.closest('#bagua-table td');
  if (td) highlight(td);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. So in short, it goes up event chain until that object is found to be stopped. I see how the .closet would be a better way to understand this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In an event listener, `this` is equivalent to `event.currentTarget`, which is the element that the listener was added to (the `table`).

`event.target` is the nested element that was actually clicked on.

So the loop is walking up the DOM hierarchy (using `target.parentNode`) from the clicked element until it reaches the table that the listener was added to.

If it reaches a `TD` element along the way, it highlights that element and returns, which breaks out of the loop.

It's roughly equivalent to:

```
highlight(event.target.closest("TD"));
```