# collapse and expand columns in html table with plus and minus by using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Pplease help me to fix when clicks on plus or minus it should work for only previous collapsed header unless all headers in table

[this example table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQrWN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ0sh.png)

```
function togglecolumns() { 
         
         $('.sub-column').toggle(); 
         $('th.collapsed').text(function (i, text) { 
             return text === '+' ? '-' : '+'; 
         }); 
}
```

Comment: Learn about the [`this` keyword in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481439/jquery-this-keyword)