# relationship between .getBoundingClientRect(), each() and $(this) - get the getBoundingClientRect for multiple elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the situation below:

```
$('h2[id*="h-"]').each(function(el) {
    console.log($(this).getBoundingClientRect());
});
```

This code is throwing the following error:

> VM2321:5 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Why?

I also tried

```
$('h2[id*="h-"]').each(function(el) {
    console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect());
});
```

But `el` just represents the index and not the element so it doesn't work

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

> Syntax domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

My syntax is correct.

How do you watch multiple elements? Is it simply not possible? Is there a better approach? Should I use something like observer.observe()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the context of the 'this' keyword with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552110/using-the-context-of-the-this-keyword-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
this.getBoundingClientRect();
```

In jQuery methods like `.each()` the `this` refers to the current DOM element.

Alternatively, in your second snippet, you could have used the *second* argument `el` of the callback function:

```
$('h2[id*="h-"]').each(function(_,el) {
    console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect());
});
```

Comment: Your second snippet wouldn't work because [the function passed to `each` takes the index as its first argument, then the element](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Also, I'm not sure why there would be a `target` property unless `ev` was an `Event` object, which has nothing to do with `each`... You are of course correct about `this`, although I'm sure there are hundreds of duplicates about that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: you are absolutely right! I mixed up `each()`with a typical event-attachment method! Corrected it. And, yes, there are probably thousands of nearly duplicate answers to this :D ...